# combine two xml files into one

Tags: php, xml, xslt

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:param name="pXml1" select="''" />
  <xsl:param name="pXml2" select="''" />
  <xsl:param name="pRoot" select="'root'" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="vXml1" select="document($pXml1)" />
    <xsl:variable name="vXml2" select="document($pXml2)" />

    <xsl:element name="{$pRoot}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="$vXml1/*/*" />
      <xsl:copy-of select="$vXml2/*/*" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The code fails when `$pXml1` contains space Ex. "a b c.xml"

How to solve it ??

Need some encode or not ?

Answer (score 1):

When being passed a string, the [`document`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-document) function expects a [URI](http://www.apps.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.html). If your XSLT processor supports it, you can use the [`str:encode-uri`](http://www.exslt.org/str/functions/encode-uri/index.html) extension function from EXSLT to URI-encode your filename.